# Mime | TypeError: typeMap[type].map is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, mime, superagent

I've installed `spotify-web-api-node` into my npm TypeScript project to retrieve data about tracks because you need an API token for that for some reason. This package seems to use `superagent`, which uses a shaded/included `mime` package. (I can find the package in the stacktrace under `/node_modules/superagent/node_modules/mime`)

When trying to run my project, when `superagent` imports `mime`, it executes `Mime.define` which finally throws `TypeError: typeMap[type].map is not a function`. I have no idea why this is happening. I found someone having a similar issue but they were able to fix it by simply doing:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

Which didn't work for me.